# Partition a sequence of tuple in scala

Tags: scala

I often write the same code to partition a sequence of tuples:

```
def groupBy[A, B](s: Seq[(A, B)]) : Map[A, Seq[B]] = s.groupBy (_._1) map { case (k, values) => (k, values.map(_._2))}
```

Is there a better way ?

Comment: Your `groupBy` signature is very specific, so there isn't a method in the standard library that does exactly this. Seems pretty concise, anyway?

Comment: Slightly more concise: `groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._1))` but then you run in to the problem with `mapValues` (http://blog.bruchez.name/2013/02/mapmap-vs-mapmapvalues.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalaz `foldMap` is clearer, although possibly less efficient:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def groupBy[A, B](l: List[(A,B)]) = l foldMap {t => Map(t._1 → List(t._2))}
```

Since Scalaz only offers typeclass instances for concrete types like `List` or `Vector` you can only use those, not `Seq`. If you want a generic version you can use the typeclass explicitly:

```
def groupBy[S[_]: Foldable, A, B](s: S[(A, B)]) =
   s foldMap {t => Map(t._1 → List(t._2))}
```

This will work for `List`, `Vector`, or generally any `S[_]: Foldable` - but still not `Seq` where you don't know the concrete type.